# Exporting PDF from InDesign makes text look thicker

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, pdf, export

First time i come across this issue:

- I export a pdf. from InDesign (both in web & print res)
- In both cases the font (Avenir) looks 'thicker' when viewed in Acrobat or Preview (regular -> looks thicker / bold -> looks bolder etc)
- The fonts are not outlined (and the PDF is not generated via Distiller)
- HOWEVER the pdf looks OK when viewed on PC

I found this very strange since the InDesign file and PDF where both created on Mac. Your input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely a preview issue. Try printing a page and check that? Or try to open via Photoshop / Google Drive / anything else you have that may render the pages differently.

Answer (score 1):

Some PDF readers are not the best rendering texts, Specially por example the letter "l" or vertical lines in general. That is only a render issue. If you are sending the pdf to print there will be no problems.

Sometimes when making a pdf for a presentation (not to be sent online) it is usefull to make all the text into curves. This way the text looks smoother.

(Sometimes it is good to do that when sending to print, to avoid any possible modification on the fonts used.)

Comment: I fully agree with your first paragraph—but not necessarily with the 2 following ones ... (I'm rounding up my 1/3 vote )